# Component export errors using '@fluentui/react', but works with 'office-ui-fabric-react'

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

Trying to get started with Microsoft's Fluent UI, but for some reason I'm getting errors that every component is not exported from the library.

Following the "Get Started"

- `npx create-react-app my-app`
- `cd my-app`
- `npm install @fluentui/react`

#### Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
...
 "@fluentui/react": "^7.111.1", // Note: office-ui-fabric is NOT a specified dependency
...
}
```

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react';

// Here I have tried 5 ways of doing the import, the first 4 are errors

// #1, from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/get-started
import { PrimaryButton } from '@fluentui/react';

// #2,3,4 are from https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui#integrating-in-your-project
// #2
import { PrimaryButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
// #3
import { PrimaryButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib-amd/Button';
// #4
import { PrimaryButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib-commonjs/Button';

// #5, works with ESLint errors that this package is not a specified dependency
import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PrimaryButton>I am a button.</PrimaryButton>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here are the errors I'm getting following each of the different imports:

1. `./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'PrimaryButton' is not exported from '@fluentui/react'.`

2, 3, 4. `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

5. Works with an expected linter warning. I'm super confused why the Get Started is importing from `@fluentui/react` and the docs contradict that by saying to import from `office-ui-fabric-react`

So my questions are:

1. Why does `import { PrimaryButton } from '@fluentui/react'` not work, but `import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react';` does?
2. Is there a global install I'm missing?
3. Why does the Get Started install `@fluentui/react` when all the starter templates use a version of `office-ui-fabric-react` as a dependency?

It also looks like doing `yarn add office-ui-fabric-react` will install `"office-ui-fabric-react": "^7.111.1"`. So I'm curious if that is the more correct approach?

Comment: Even, I'm too facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues stems from a bad release that has since been resolved. The current working version is `7.113.0` as stated in [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/13105) (thank you @onzur for posting that).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an issue with the latest version. Try using version 7.110.5. You can do that by  calling
`npm install @fluentui/react@7.110.5 --save`

I opened an issue in github: https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/13105

When I reverted it seemed to work.

Comment: Dope, I followed up on your GH issues and can confirm that 7.110.5 is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with 7.111.0 version and it is working fine. You can check out here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/fluent-ui-react-demo?file=index.js

I think issue is with v7.111.1 which was released yesterday.

Comment: Looks like everything is updated now. Was able to confirm the fix pushed out yesterday `7.113.0` is working